# mysqli_query() giving no response, even mysqli_error() giving no error message

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to insert data into `mysqli` database. Connection to database established successfully. But data is not inserted.Even `mysqli_eror()` not showing any error.

My code:

```
<?php

  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","vote") ||
  die("couldn't connect to database");

  if(!$con){
    die("Could't connect to database. try again");
  }
  else{
    echo "connected to db"; /* connection established successfully */
    $query="INSERT INTO candidate(ID,name,email,password)
    VALUES(0,'$name','$email','$password' ) ";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    echo ($result)? '1':mysqli_error($con);
  }

?>
```

Going to `phpmyadmin` I run the same *insert query* and data was inserted.

But this code is not inserting data. Even **mysqli_error($con)** returning a **empty string**.

I am using `XAMPP` on `Ubuntu 14.04`

[Please ask if any more information you need]

Comment: Remove `||` condition form your connection

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I removed `||` and put `or` . That solved. Why?

Comment: Because you condition return either Boolean `true or false` not mysqli connection object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is creating the problem,

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","vote") ||
      die("couldn't connect to database");
```

Change it to

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","vote") or
                                                           ^
      die("couldn't connect to database");
```

Or

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "vote");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

If you are not seeing error, try adding, `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the file.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to help. But problem was with `||` . Can you tell why `||` doesn't work?

Comment: || is returning Boolean value.... That's the mistake... U need object if mysqli...